# Picking a Random html page from an Array but each page only once (Plus first two and last two pages should be same all the time)

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a Html survey with multiple pages.

I want to have the first and last two pages in the same order for all users.

But I want to have middle pages random.

Here is my code which works and creates random pages however, it does not load pages and show them as text.

```js
let randomlinks = [href = 'Task1A.html', href = 'Task1B.html', href = 'Task1C.html', href = 'Task1D.html',
  href = 'Task2A.html', href = 'Task2B.html', href = 'Task2C.html', href = 'Task2D.html',
  href = 'Task3A.html', href = 'Task3B.html', href = 'Task3C.html', href = 'Task3D.html',
  href = 'Task4A.html', href = 'Task4B.html', href = 'Task4C.html', href = 'Task4D.html'
]

let getRandomPage = function*(array) {
  let clone = [...array]
  let getIndex = function(arr) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
  }
  while (clone.length !== 0) yield clone.splice(getIndex(clone), 1).pop();
 
 return window.location = 'Final.html'
};


let randoms = getRandomPage(randomlinks);

const logRandom = () => {
  let val = randoms.next().value;
  if (val !== undefined) document.querySelector('html').textContent = val;
};
   

const load = () => {
  document.getElementById('random').addEventListener('click', logRandom);
  
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load)
```

```html
<button type="submit" id="random" class="btn"><a  >Next </a></button>
```

[image]

Also, this code worked and loaded pages however it was an infinite loop and I want to have each page once.

```js
let randomlinks = [href = 'Task1A.html', href = 'Task1B.html', href = 'Task1C.html', href = 'Task1D.html',
  href = 'Task2A.html', href = 'Task2B.html', href = 'Task2C.html', href = 'Task2D.html',
  href = 'Task3A.html', href = 'Task3B.html', href = 'Task3C.html', href = 'Task3D.html',
  href = 'Task4A.html', href = 'Task4B.html', href = 'Task4C.html', href = 'Task4D.html'
]

function randomlink() {
  window.location = randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomlinks.length)]

}
```

```html
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn"><a onClick='randomlink()' >Next </a></button>
```

Comment: `return window.location = 'Final.html'` will load a new page when encountered  - is that the expected result?

Comment: Just shuffle the array after popping and shifting it

Comment: Yes after each Task is selected only once I want to return to Final.html to finish the survey

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to shuffle the pages first while retaining the first and last page. The function `shuffle` below will do that for you. `unshift` will add the first page while `push` will add the last page.

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]
    ];
  }

  return array;
}

let randomlinks = [
  href = 'Task1A.html', href = 'Task1B.html', href = 'Task1C.html', href = 'Task1D.html',
  href = 'Task2A.html', href = 'Task2B.html', href = 'Task2C.html', href = 'Task2D.html',
  href = 'Task3A.html', href = 'Task3B.html', href = 'Task3C.html', href = 'Task3D.html',
  href = 'Task4A.html', href = 'Task4B.html', href = 'Task4C.html', href = 'Task4D.html'
];

shuffle(randomlinks);
console.log('shuffled', randomlinks);

//add first page
randomlinks.unshift('FirstPage.html');
//add last page
randomlinks.push('LastPage.html');

console.log('final', randomlinks);

function nextPage() {
  let cont = document.getElementById('test');
  cont && (cont.innerText = randomlinks.shift() || "No More")
}
```

```html
<button id="random" class="btn" onclick="nextPage()">Next</button>
<h1 id="test">Welcome</h1>
```

**EDIT**:

Since you wanted to be able to redirect to the next page on click, obviously you'd need to store the shuffled items (`randomlinks`) into something which can be accessed by all your pages. You can either save it into a database or something. Maybe [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)? It's up to you.

Comment: Well, thank you @Geoman Yabes, but this didn't work. It does not load .HTML pages. It only shows their names. Other codes work as well with the same problem of not loading the page.

Comment: Of course it wont. Your question is "Picking". To redirect, you can do `window.location.href = the html page` but that would remove all the code from the above snippet. You might need to store `randomlinks` to `sessionStorage` but that would be a separate question.